# Cygwin: difference between '\rm -fr' and 'rm -fr' command?

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin

I have one shell script running on windows environment on cygwin environment. This script have one purging function which deletes certain folder on the system bases on certain condition.

I prepare the list of all the folder that I want to delete and then use following command:

```
rm -rfv $purge (where purge is the list of directories I want to delete)
```

Now when I tested this script, the directories are not getting deleted at all. First I thought  there is some issue with by purge list, but on debugging I came to know that purge list is fine.

After lots of debugging and trials I just made small change in command:

```
\rm -rfv $purge
```

It just a kind of hit and trial and script starts working fine. 
Now as far as I know \rm and rm -f both means forceful delete.

Now how can I justify this that why 'rm -f' what now working earlier but '\rm -f' did.
I want to know the basic difference between these two commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `rm` can be (in theory) one of:

- shell builtin command (however I don't know any shell with such builtin)
- external command (most likely /bin/rm)
- a shell function
- an alias

If you put `\` before it (or quote any part of it, for example `"rm"` or even `'r'm`) shell will ignore all aliases (but not functions).

As jlliagre mentioned, you can ask shell what `rm` is and what is `\rm` using `type` builtin.

**Experiment:**

```
$ type rm
rm is /bin/rm
$ rm() { echo "FUNC"; command rm "$@"; }
$ type rm
rm is a function
$ alias rm='echo ALIAS; rm -i'
$ type rm
rm is aliased to `echo ALIAS; rm -i'
```

Now, we have alias `rm`, function `rm` and original external `rm` command:
Let's see how to call each other:

```
$ rm   # this will call alias, calling function calling real rm
$ rm
ALIAS
FUNC
rm: missing operand
$ \rm  # this will ignore alias, and call function calling real rm
FUNC
rm: missing operand
$ command rm  # this will ignore any builtin, alias or function and call rm according to PATH
rm: missing operand
```

To understand it deeply, see `help builtin`,  `help command`, `help alias` and `man sh`.

Comment: I have also tried giving exact path of the rm command like /usr/bin/rm -fr . I think this is equal to \rm -fr... right ?? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you have /usr/bin/rm first in the PATH and you don't have any rm() function defined, then yes. Note, that on most systems rm is in /bin/ (not /usr/bin/), since it's an essential system command.

Comment: even after using absolute path for the rm command in my script.. purging function was not working in script... Only after if have used \rm then only its start working.... Do we have a good explanation for this... Kindly correct me if I am getting confused somewhere..

Comment: @dhroove: this is strange. You might have different rm commands. Can you paste `type rm` and `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: here it is: $ type rm
rm is hashed (/usr/bin/rm)  |                                        
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32

Answer (score 5):

That means your rm command is aliased <s>or a function</s>. Backslashing it tells the shell to use the real rm command.

Edit: You can tell what `rm` refers to with the `type` command, eg:

```
$ type rm
rm is /bin/rm
```

.

```
$ type rm
rm is aliased to `rm -i'
```

.

```
$ type rm
rm is a function
...
```

Comment: but when I run same command 'rm -fr' on cygwin terminal to delete directory and sub directory then it works fine... Than why it is happening in shell script only ? :(

Comment: @dhroove because in your cygwin environment,`rm` is not defined as a function/alias.  Your startup scripts are different in the two environments.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : two environments you mentioned above are you talking about the environment in which script runs and environment in which cygwin terminals runs ???

Comment: Adding to above case.. When I type only rm on cygwin terminal it gives me error message                                       
$ \rm
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.. I think this means rm is defined as function in cygwin environment... Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `type -a rm` will show you *all* the possible meanings of `rm`, in the order in which the shell will try them.  `help type` for more information on the `type` command.  (This assumes you're using bash, which is the default shell on Cygwin.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: `type -a` and `help type` are non standard. They will likely work on cygwin usual shells but I prefer to suggest `type command` alone, which works with all POSIX shells.

Comment: @jlliagre: Since the question was tagged Cygwin, and since I explicitly stated the assumption that the OP is using bash, I don't see a problem. But yes, it's useful to know that they're non-standard.